# Unable to redirect .htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What i need is if any one will hit on mydomain.com/mydirectory/about-us-new then it should stay on page and if anyone hit any other url on the same domain it should redirect user to google.com.

I am using following code for this purpose:

```
#urls to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydirectory/about-us-new$

#send to root
RewriteRule . http://google.com? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Your code looks fine just have RewriteRule like this: `RewriteRule ^ http://google.com? [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the rewrite condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydirectory/about\-us\-new$
```

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite code you provided above works for me.

If mod_rewrite is installed, you may try making sure the RewriteEngine is enabled.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/url/here$
    RewriteRule . http://www.google.com? [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```